# Solve an overdetermined system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, least-squares

I have doubt to solve this system of equations

\begin{cases}
x+y=r_1\\
x+z=c_1\\
x+w=d_1\\
y+z=d_2\\
y+w=c_2\\
z+w=r_2
\end{cases}

Is it an overdetermined system because I see there are more equations than unknowns.

Can we just solve this system in a simple way?

Comment: The system is indeed overdetermined and will only have a solution if the constants in the right-hand sides of the equation satisfy certain conditions.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalEquation.html

Answer (score 7):

Your system is described by the augmented matrix
$$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & r_{1} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & c_{1} \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & d_{1} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & d_{2} \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & c_{2} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & r_{2}
\end{array}\right]
$$
Row-reducing the system gives
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \, c_{1} + d_{1} + \frac{1}{2} \, d_{2} - \frac{1}{2} \, r_{1} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \, c_{1} - \frac{1}{2} \, d_{2} + \frac{1}{2} \, r_{1} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \, c_{1} + \frac{1}{2} \, d_{2} + \frac{1}{2} \, r_{1} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \, c_{1} + \frac{1}{2} \, d_{2} - \frac{1}{2} \, r_{1} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c_{1} + c_{2} - d_{1} - d_{2} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -d_{1} - d_{2} + r_{1} + r_{2}
\end{array}\right]
$$
This implies that your system is solvable if and only if
\begin{align*}
c_1+c_2-d_1-d_2 &= 0 \\
-d_1-d_2+r_1+r_2 &= 0
\end{align*}
If these conditions are satisfied, then your system is solved by
\begin{align*}
w &=-\frac{1}{2} \, c_{1} + d_{1} + \frac{1}{2} \, d_{2} - \frac{1}{2} \, r_{1} \\
x &= \frac{1}{2} \, c_{1} - \frac{1}{2} \, d_{2} + \frac{1}{2} \, r_{1}\\
y &= -\frac{1}{2} \, c_{1} + \frac{1}{2} \, d_{2} + \frac{1}{2} \, r_{1}\\
z &=\frac{1}{2} \, c_{1} + \frac{1}{2} \, d_{2} - \frac{1}{2} \, r_{1}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**

Write the system of linear equations in matrix form: set
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&0\\1&0&1&0\\1&0&0&1\\0&1&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix},\quad
X=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{bmatrix},\quad B=\begin{bmatrix}r_1\\c_1\\d_1\\d_2\\c_2\\w_2\end{bmatrix}$$
$A$ is the matrix of a linear mapping from $\mathbf R^4$ to  $\mathbf R^6$ (supposing the base field is $\mathbf R$) and the linear system can be written as 
$$AX=B.$$
Now this system has solutions, by definition, if $B$ is in the image of the linear map.  A criterion for this is the following:

> The linear system $\;AX=B$ has a solution if and only if the matrix $A$ and the augmented matrix $(A\mid B)$ have the same rank. Furthermore, the set of solutions, if any, is an affine space directed by the subvectorspace $\ker A$ and has codimension the rank of $A$.

Using row reduction, you should find $A$ has maximal rank ($4$), and if the augmented matrix also has  rank $4$,  there is a unique solution, which you'll find with *full* row reduction.

Comment: The maximal rank of the augmented matrix is $5$; we need that the augmented matrix has rank $4$ too.

Comment: @egreg: I completely messed up with rows and columns… Thanks for pointing the error. I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Start with the linear system
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} x &= b \\
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 x_{1} \\
 x_{2} \\
 x_{3} \\
 x_{4} 
\end{array}
\right]
%
&=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 b_{1} \\
 b_{2} \\
 b_{3} \\
 b_{4} \\
 b_{5} \\
 b_{6}
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$
We see that
$$
  \mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{6\times 4}_{4}, \quad
  b \in \mathbb{R}^{6}, \quad
  x \in \mathbb{R}^{4};
$$
that is $\mathbf{A}$ has $m=6$ rows, $n=4$ columns, and has rank $\rho=4$. The nullspace vectors reveal 
$$
\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{A}^{*}\right) = \text{span} \left\{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
  0 \\
 -1 \\
 -1 \\
  0 \\
  1
\end{array}
\right]
,
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  0 \\
  1 \\
 -1 \\
 -1 \\
  1 \\
  0
\end{array}
\right]
%
\right\}
$$

Let's look at this problem using the method of least squares. As long as the data vector $b$ is not in the nullspace, there will be a least squares solution. The normal equations offer easy resolution:
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} x &= \mathbf{A}^{*} b \\[5pt]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 x_{1} \\
 x_{2} \\
 x_{3} \\
 x_{4} 
\end{array}
\right]
%
 &=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 b_1 + b_2 + b_3 \\
 b_1 + b_4 + b_5 \\
 b_2 + b_4 + b_6 \\
 b_3 + b_5 + b_6 
\end{array}
\right].
%
\end{align}
$$
The least squares solution is 
$$
\begin{align}
 x_{LS} &= \left( \mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{*} b \\[5pt]
%
 &=
%
\frac{1}{12}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
  5 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
 -1 &  5 & -1 & -1 \\
 -1 & -1 &  5 & -1 \\
 -1 & -1 & -1 &  5 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 b_1 + b_2 + b_3 \\
 b_1 + b_4 + b_5 \\
 b_2 + b_4 + b_6 \\
 b_3 + b_5 + b_6 
\end{array}
\right]\\[5pt]
% 
 &=
%
\frac{1}{6}
\left[
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcrcrc}
 2 b_1 & + & 2 b_2 & + & 2 b_3 & - & b_4 & - & b_5 & - & b_6 \\ 
 2 b_1 & - & b_2 & - & b_3 & + & 2 b_4 & + & 2 b_5 & - & b_6 \\
  -b_1 & + & 2 b_2 & - & b_3 & + & 2 b_4 & - & b_5 & + & 2 b_6 \\
  -b_1 & - & b_2 & + & 2 b_3 & - & b_4 & + & 2 b_5 & + & 2 b_6 
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$
Because the problem has full column rank $m=\rho=4$, $\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}\right) = \left\{ \mathbf{0} \right\}$ the solution is unique.

Is this the direct solution where $\mathbf{A}x - b = 0$? The residual error vector shows the constraints required for a direct solution.
$$
  r(x) = \mathbf{A}x - b =
%
\frac{1}{6}
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcrcrc}
 -2 b_{1} & + & b_{2} & + & b_{3} & + & b_{4} & + & b_{5} & - & 2 b_{6} \\
    b_{1} & - & 2 b_{2} & + & b_{3} & + & b_{4} & - & 2 b_{5} & + & b_{6} \\
    b_{1} & + & b_{2} & - & 2 b_{3} & - & 2 b_{4} & + & b_{5} & + & b_{6} \\
    b_{1} & + & b_{2} & - & 2 b_{3} & - & 2 b_{4} & + & b_{5} & + & b_{6} \\
    b_{1} & - & 2 b_{2} & + & b_{3} & + & b_{4} & - & 2 b_{5} & + & b_{6} \\
 -2 b_{1} & + & b_{2} & + & b_{3} & + & b_{4} & + & b_{5} & - & 2 b_{6}
\end{array}
\right]
$$