# Solve system of overdetermined simultaneous equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, systems-of-equations

I have a large number (tens not hundreds) of parameters: **a<sub>1</sub>**, **a<sub>2</sub>**, **a<sub>3</sub>** ... , **a<sub>n</sub>** and **b<sub>1</sub>**, **b<sub>2</sub>**, **b<sub>3</sub>** ... , **b<sub>n</sub>** which I want to find using linear algebra.

And a system of simultaneous equations:

- **a<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub> = 4**
- **a<sub>2</sub>b<sub>1</sub> = 2**
- ...
- **a<sub>4</sub>b<sub>7</sub> = 3**
- **a<sub>7</sub>b<sub>4</sub> = 0**
- ...

**Note:**

- these formulas always take the form **a<sub>n</sub>b<sub>m</sub> = x**
- **x** is always a positive integer (or zero)
- the equations always come in pairs: **a<sub>n</sub>b<sub>m</sub> = x** & **a<sub>m</sub>b<sub>n</sub> = y**
- we never get **a<sub>n</sub>b<sub>n</sub> = x** equations (e.g. **a** and **b** values with the same index in the same equation)
- each parameter (e.g. **a<sub>1</sub>** or **b<sub>6</sub>**) will occur in multiple equations
- not ever combination of **a<sub>n</sub>b<sub>m</sub>** will necessarily be present in the system of equations
- To constrain the system, I'm happy to assume the mean of the **b** values is **1**
- There will be enough equations to over constrain the parameters, I'm looking for the optimal solution, not an exact solution.

Is it possible to pose this problem in a matrix form such that I can solve it using matrix inversion and a QR transform? I'm currently using `scipy.optimize.minimize()` which is very slow.

If the formulas took the form **a<sub>n</sub> + b<sub>m</sub> = x** this would be relatively simple to solve using something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2179941/647170), but the parameters are multiplied, not added :-(.

Part of the problem I'm having while trying to find a mathematical solution is I'm not sure what to call this sort of problem. Is there a name for problems like this?

Comment: Take logarithms

Comment: Please use mathjax. This [guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good start.

Comment: @Bananach That was my initial thought, too.  But what about $a_7 b_4 = 0$?

Comment: @RobPratt, very good point I thought logs would solve this but I don't know how to work around the zero case.

Comment: Replace zeros by small positive numbers, or try solving it assuming that any subset of your variables is zero and the rest isn't

Comment: That's what I thought, I guess I could even add a small number to all values.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to find a non-linear least squares solution to something that looks like

$$ Y_{k\ell} - a_k \: b_\ell = 0\text{ .} $$

We seek to minimize the squared residuals between the data and the model you use to fit the data. For you it would look something like this.

$$R = \sum_{k\neq\ell} \big(Y_{k\ell} - a_k \: b_\ell\big)^2 $$

Minimization will happen when the gradient $\nabla R$ with respect to all parameters $a$ and $b$ are equal to zero. Taking derivatives to find equations

$$\begin{align} \dfrac{\partial R}{\partial a_j} &= 0\\\dfrac{\partial R}{\partial b_j} &= 0 \end{align}$$

you should now be able to solve a least-squares system using Levenberg-Marquardt or whatever algorithm you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think the best solution is that suggested by @Bananach above - take logs of the equations: `log(a1*b12 == log(a1) * log(b2)` with that it can be solve like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860348/solve-an-overdetermined-system-of-linear-equations/2179941#2179941).

Comment: Yeah that should be valid. There are some edge cases however where taking the log of your equations and using linear least squares is far from the actual least squares solution. You should be fine here though. If curious, take a look at [this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4113620/why-is-there-more-weight-on-smaller-y-values-in-transformed-linear-regression-as)

Comment: I second the least squares approach, and [scipy has an API dedicated to that](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#least-squares-minimization-least-squares).